# ionic build package error for ios - code sign error

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

I'm struggling in getting my app ready for submission to Apple App Store...

I have valid ios development and distribution certificates and provisioning profiles.

I can successfully build my app via Xcode using development certificates and provisioning profile and works fines on test device i.e. iPhone 4s.

However, when I change the 'Code Signing Identify' setting in Xcode to use my Apple distribution certificates and set the Provisioning Profile to the production profile, the app builds successfully but when Xcode tries to run the app on the iPhone, it throws an error: 'App installation failed. A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found'.

Not sure if the above is related, when I try to build the app using ionic package CLI command; 'ionic package build ios --release --profile [PROFILE-TAG]' I get this error:

CheckCheck dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

For info, I have created the ionic security profile as suggested here: [Security Profiles](http://docs.ionic.io/v2.0.0-beta/docs/security-profiles)

I'm using:
OS X El Capitan
Xcode 7.2.1
Cordova 6.0.0
Ionic version: 1.2.4

Happy to provide more info if required. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned in the question

> However, when I change the 'Code Signing Identify' setting in Xcode to use my Apple distribution certificates and set the
>   Provisioning Profile to the production profile, the app builds
>   successfully but when Xcode tries to run the app on the iPhone, it
>   throws an error: 'App installation failed. A valid provisioning
>   profile for this executable was not found'.

You can't directly run the build with the production profile/certificate in the device, to directly run from the xcode you have to build it with the development provision profile

If you want to test your production build before submisson you can download it with the **TestFlight**, it will be easier and better way of checking the build as same build will go for the submisson

If you need help with testflight you can refer doc here: 
[Apple Doc:Beta testing with testfligjt](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)
[Apple Doc: Distribute your app with testflight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight.html) 
[Ray wenderlich Testflight tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

App which signed with an App Store provisioning profile can only be installed that downloaded from App Store, and for testing production behavior, you can generate an Ad-Hoc profile to sign your app. [Ad Hoc Provisioning Profiles in Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW13) and [How to](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204270188-iOS-Creating-an-Ad-Hoc-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile)

Comment: I have just tried with Ad Hoc profile, I can build the app and run it on my test device, thank you!  I now want to package it for submission, so do I now use the production Provisioning Profile to build it? Also I'm still getting the same error for ionic package build.

Comment: @GreenDome yes for the app store submission you need to use the Production provision profile to build it

Comment: @GreenDome Sorry I did not used Ionic framework, I just used its Ionicons in my [IconFontKit](https://github.com/ElfSundae/IconFontKit)